# python & numpy: forcing the matrix to contain values known to range from x to y?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, memory-management

I use numpy to prototype a mathematical code. My mathematics contain only probabilities on which i perform matrix arithmetics (multiplication, dot function in numpy). As I know that all values range from 0 to 1, I wonder if I can force numpy to code values (saving memory or enjoy more precision) on 32/64bit but ranging with an upper boundary fixed at 1?

```
try1 = numpy.array([1.0,0.2564654646546],dtype='f16')
```

Can dtype be forced to range from x to y with a same amount of memory per value?

Comment: Not easily, no. The numpy datatypes are names for low-level datatypes in the underlying C code.

Comment: Since they're probabilities, shouldn't they be in the range [0, 1] rather than (-inf, 1]? (And shouldn't you be computing with logarithms to retain numerical stability?)

Comment: @larsmans: logarithms are no better if dot-product (=>additions)  is frequently used.

Comment: Indeed Larsman, I edited --> [0,1] ;o)

Comment: do you mean you want to use fixed-point arithmetic rather than floating point?

Comment: The only way to do this would be to follow @wim's suggestion, and use fixed point arithmetic. However, this can get you into overflow problems if all your intermediate values aren't also within the same range - which they are unlikely to be if you are doing matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, numpy arrays don't support fixed point arithmetic and I haven't heard of any plans to add it.  If you are interested in playing with that stuff, you could check out matlab's [fixed-pt toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/fixed/), or if you really love mathematics you can cook your own using integer datatypes and keeping track of the 'point'.

The way floating point works is already pretty neat though and I'm not sure you would gain a heap of precision per bit just with the knowledge that numbers are in [0,1].  Floating point is similar to scientific notation, increasing the number of bits mainly gives you more "significant digits" rather than (just) a larger range of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose nowadays you can acchieve this with:

```
a = np.linspace(0, 1, number_of_points)
```